# How to correctly configure SQL Server to local access a mdf file

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2015

I have created a software in WPF that accesses a `.mdf` SQL Server database file. The software was coded in Visual Studio 2015 Community edition and I used SQL Server 2014.

Everything works fine, but when I created a setup wizard project it gives in the prerequisites list only SQL Server 2012 as a choice. Problem is that the software does not work with SQL Server 2012. When I install my software on a virtual machine, it also installs .NET 4.5.2 and SQL Server 2012, but when I try to run my program it tries to access the database (`.mdf` file) and it throws this error:

> system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception (0x80131904) a network related or instance specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. The specific LocalDB does not exists)

How can I change SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2014 in the prerequisites list? Or how can I change my code to SQL Server 2012. I looked a lot of times through it and in the settings, but I did not find where it says it needs SQL Server 2014 or better said `sqllocaldb v12.0`

Or any other solution to this problem is welcomed.

Thank you.

Comment: what is your connection string ?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. THe conenction string is: @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=" + databaseWindowsPath + ";Integrated Security=True";

Comment: change the connection string with this Intial Catalog='your database name' rather then attachedDbFileName

Comment: I does not work. Please be aware that I connect with C#, not in WPF